# Autofac decorating with assembly scanning

Tags: c#, decorator, autofac

I'm trying to build a query pipeline using Autofac but can't seem to figure out how to decorate this properly. The workflow is

*Retrieve from cache > Retrieve from DB > Store in cache > Transform*

Below is the current configuration

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
    .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Transform"))
    .As(o => o.GetInterfaces()
        .Where(i => i.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IQuery<,>)))
        .Select(i => new KeyedService("Transform", i))
    );

builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
    typeof(SaveToCache<,>),
    typeof(IQuery<,>),
    fromKey: "Transform",
    toKey: "SaveCache"
);

builder.RegisterDecorator<IQuery<GetPerson, PersonDto>>(
    (x, decorator) => new GetPersonQuery(decorator),
    fromKey: "SaveCache",
    toKey: "QueryDb"
);

builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
    typeof(RetrieveFromCache<,>),
    typeof(IQuery<,>),
    fromKey: "QueryDb"
);
```

So the chain works, however the registration below isn't ideal as new queries need to be manually registered

```
builder.RegisterDecorator<IQuery<GetPerson, PersonDto>>(
    (x, decorator) => new GetPersonQuery(decorator),
    fromKey: "SaveCache",
    toKey: "QueryDb"
);
```

So is there anyway to register a decorator using some form of scanning mechanism?

I guess you could scan the assembly and find the concrete implementations and then register it, but its still not as straight forward :(

```
var type = typeof(IQuery<,>);

var queries = assemblies
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
    .Where(y => y.GetInterfaces().Any(z => z.IsGenericType && z.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == type) && y.Name.EndsWith("Query"));

foreach (var query in queries)
{
    // ?
}
```